# Convert a numeric utf-8 sequence to a string

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I need to convert strings of this kind (where unicode chars are stored in a special way):

```
Ce correspondant a cherch=C3=A9 =C3=A0 vous joindre
```

... to a valid utf-8 string, like this:

```
Ce correspondant a cherché à vous joindre
```

I wrote the code to extract the numerical utf-8 sequence from this simple syntax 
(`=XX=XX` with each `X` as an hex digit), but I'm stuck when I try to convert this
sequence to a printable char : it's a utf-8 sequence, not a Unicode code point, so the `chr()`
built-in is not useful here (or at least, not alone).

#### Briefly:

I need to transform this example value:

```
utf8_sequence = 0xC3A9
```

to this string:

```
return_value = 'é'
```

The Unicode code point for this letter is `U+00E9`, but I don't know how to pass from 
the utf-8 sequence to this given Unicode code point, which could be used with `chr()`.

#### My code

Here is my code, with a comment showing the place where i'm stuck:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# coding: utf-8

import re

test_string = 'Ce correspondant a cherch=C3=A9 =C3=A0 vous joindre'


# SHOULD convert a string like '=C3=A9' to the equivalent Unicode 
# char, in this example 'é'.
def vmg_to_unicode(in_string):

    whole_sequence = 0 # Stores the numerical utf-8 sequence
    in_length = len(in_string)
    num_bytes = int(in_length / 3) # Number of bytes
    bit_weight = num_bytes << 3 # Weight of char in bits (little-endian)

    for i in range(0, in_length, 3): # For each char:
        bit_weight -= 8
        # Extract the hex number inside '=XX':
        hex_number = in_string[i+1:][:2]
        # Build the utf-8 sequence:
        whole_sequence += int(hex_number, 16) << bit_weight

    # At this point, whole_sequence contains for example 0xC3A9

    # The following doesn't work, chr() expect a Unicode code point:
    # return chr(whole_sequence)

    # HOW CAN I RETURN A STRING LIKE 'é' THERE?

    # Only for debug:
    return '[0x{:X}]'.format(whole_sequence)


# In a whole string, convert all occurences of patterns like '=C3=A9'
# to their equivalent Unicode chars.
def vmg_transform(in_string):

    # Get all occurences:
    results = ( m for m in re.finditer('(=[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})+', in_string) )

    index, out = (0, '')

    for result in results:
        # Concat the unchanged text:
        out += in_string[index:result.start()]
        # Concat the replacement of the matched pattern:
        out += vmg_to_unicode(result.group(0))
        index = result.end()

    # Concat the end of the unchanged string:
    out += in_string[index:]

    return out


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('In  : "{}"'.format(test_string))
    print('Out : "{}"'.format(vmg_transform(test_string)))
```

#### Current output

```
In  : "Ce correspondant a cherch=C3=A9 =C3=A0 vous joindre"
Out : "Ce correspondant a cherch[0xC3A9] [0xC3A0] vous joindre"
```

#### Wanted output

```
In  : "Ce correspondant a cherch=C3=A9 =C3=A0 vous joindre"
Out : "Ce correspondant a cherché à vous joindre"
```

Comment: Are you getting this from an email?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: it's from the .vmg file format, a text format used to export SMS from some mobile phones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- first create a `bytearray`
- populate it
- then convert to `bytes` and decode according to UTF-8 encoding

Here's the part of your code to adapt:

```
    s = bytearray()

    for i in range(0, in_length, 3): # For each char:
        bit_weight -= 8
        # Extract the hex number inside '=XX':
        hex_number = in_string[i+1:][:2]
        # Build the utf-8 sequence:
        s.append(int(hex_number,16))

    # At this point, whole_sequence contains for example 0xC3A9

    # The following doesn't work, chr() expect a Unicode code point:
    # return chr(whole_sequence)

    # HOW CAN I RETURN A STRING LIKE 'é' THERE?

    # Only for debug:
    return bytes(s).decode("utf-8")
```

result:

```
In  : "Ce correspondant a cherch=C3=A9 =C3=A0 vous joindre"
Out : "Ce correspondant a cherché à vous joindre"
```